# App to schedule Android power off / on at specified times?

Tags: android, scheduling, battery, power-management

As per [New Android 9 'phone - where is “schedule power off / on”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232818/new-android-9-phone-where-is-schedule-power-off-on?) (now closed, with no answer, so presumably unanswerable), I go a new 'phone and can't find a setting to schedule power off /on overnight, to save battery life.

A comment there says that it is not a stock Android feature, so, id there an app for it?

I realize that it can't be "power off", just deep sleep, but the end result would be the same.

Preferably gratis, but I would pay a few europounddollars.

Note: Android 9

Comment: Power off shouldn't be too hard (look e.g. at Tasker). But how should an app tell the phone to power on when it's powered off and thus the app is not running? To my knowledge, only few devices have such a functionality at all. Maybe you can outline your use-case a bit more? If it would eg suffice to send the phone to a "very power-saving state" overnight (like cut all networks, switch off whatever else, and restore to "normal" at wake-up time), there will be possibilities. Important detail is also whether the device is rooted (to deal with CPU freqs etc).

Comment: Izzy, as I mentioned, I do not believe that it is a true power off, just a very deep sleep, with almost everything disabled. Obviously, it ***can*** be done, as Ulefone ***has*** done it, but it is apparently not part of Android itself. Tasker is a possibility. I will search around & see if I can beat you to an answer :-)

Comment: I understood that. We've had that question before, also on Android.SE. Such a feature must be part of the firmware and, as I already mentioned, only few devices have it. And yes, I use Tasker for that, in the way described: shutting off all non-essentials, but leave enough on so the alarm clock can fire in the morning. For a while I enabled "wake mode" 5min before the alarm clock as I had used a radio stream to wake me up ;)

Comment: Part of the firmware - that must be it. This time, I bought the budget model All prevous weretop of the range